# After restarting terminal, Brew commands not working and getting some error in terminal

Tags: zsh, macos, homebrew, brew

I have macOS Monterey(v12.3) and had installed brew with exact guidelines shown in youtube videos. But brew commands work only if I run in the same terminal session. When I restart the terminal and try to run the brew command it shows the following error:

```
zsh: command not found: brew
```

I have tried to install the brew multiple time but every time same thing happens. I am new to MacOS. Please help.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Apple Silicon machines, Homebrew installs itself in `/opt/homebrew` rather than in `/usr/local/bin` as on Intel-based machines. I suspect that you are running on a Silicon machine. The `/opt/homebrew/` directory isn't part of the standard `PATH`. To accommodate this, it is [suggested](https://mac.install.guide/ruby/3.html) to setup a `~/.zprofile`:

> Add Homebrew to your PATH in `~/.zprofile`:
>
> ```
> echo 'eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"' >> ~/.zprofile
> eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
> ```

(the first line adds the code to `~/.zprofile` and the second runs it in the current shell)